# RecyclerView within a scrollable fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement the following scenario:

[image]

So, theres a screen with two sections:

- section A is a header and a horizontal scroll.
- section B is a header with subtitle, and a vertical, *endless* scroll

Now I want this screen to behave the following way:

Scrolling vertically anywhere will bring the whole section A up until the subtitle, which pins to the top (sticky); While this happens scroll in section B is also going up. After the subtitle is pinned, then if you keep scrolling B will continue showing more elements.

Scrolling in the other direction will bring first the whole section A, and when this is expanded, swipe to refresh is triggered for both sections.

Now I tried with `NestedScrollView`, but this messes up with my `recyclerview` which has endless scrolling, cause then the `RecyclerView` cannot actually recycle the views (thus accumulating items and eventually going OOM).

I also tried putting everything from section A into an appbar and using coordinatorlayout to pin subtitle and move everything up, but no matter which combination of `enterAlways`|`enterAlwaysCollapsed`|`scroll`|etc I use, the behavior is never the intended: Most of the time Swipe is triggered when pulling down even if section A is not fully visible.

This screen might seem like a menial task but combining scrolls in Android is proving to be a nightmare.

Comment: Last time I had to do that I've used [this library](https://github.com/bgogetap/StickyHeaders)

Comment: this is a sticky header within a recyclerview

Comment: Yeah so this is exactly what you want to do. You want a list of things and headers and you want the headers to be sticky. The only 'complicated' thing is you want your first item to be different than the rest. So the first item just needs to be another recycler or a ViewPager depending on what you want

Comment: @Eselfar no its not, its not so easy, I need the whole screen working as a scrollable element, however nesting a RecyclerView within a ScrollView breaks the RecyclerView cause it cannot recycle its views due to not knowing its own size.

Comment: It's because you don't need the ScrollView. You need only a RecyclerView. Then the RecyclerView has 3 kinds of items: A special item ('A' in your mock up), a sticky header, and a standard item. The 'special' item is another recyclerView or a viewpager and manage it's own list of items. But it's just one item of the main RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 Recycleview , one for horizontal with header and second for vertical with Header . Please check this [link](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter). It may helpful to you.

Comment: this is not the issue, but how to handle the scrolling of the whole screen + the two recyclerviews

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote one pull to refresh behaviors kit [nestrefresh](https://github.com/ToDou/nestrefresh). You can add scrollable child in header and also add sticky header as TabLayout. Pull all child can refresh with pull-to-refresh effect.